# Checking if reducing iterator points to a valid element

Tags: c++

I need to know if I can reduce the iterator and have a valid object. The below errors out because I reduce the iterator by 1 which doesn't exist. How can I know that so I don't get the error?

```
ticks.push_front(Tick(Vec3(0, 0, 5), 0));
ticks.push_front(Tick(Vec3(0, 0, 8), 100));
ticks.push_front(Tick(Vec3(0, 0, 10), 200));

bool found = false;
    list<Tick, allocator<Tick>>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = ticks.begin(); iter != ticks.end(); ++iter)
    {
        Tick t = (*iter);

        if (214>= t.timestamp)
        {
            prior = t;
            if (--iter != ticks.end())
            {
                next = (*--iter);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to find the entries directly "above" and directly "below" the value 214 in the list. If only 1 exists then I don't care. I need above and below to exist.

Comment: `if (200 >= t.timestamp)` Aaargh, my eyes! (I know, not a constructive comment...)

Comment: ?? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why not `t.timestamp <= 200`? That's how most people write their conditions, IINM.

Comment: I guess my brain works differently. To me the other way makes more sense. Since they mean the thing, why would "most" people write that.

Comment: To each their own, they say :)

Comment: @user441521 Also known as *Yoda conditions*. Like "If greater than 200 is the timestamp"..

Comment: @jrok there's a growing movement to write all comparisons with constants by putting the constant first.  The primary motive being that if you ALWAYS do it, you never have a problem with writing `if(i = 0)` since `if(0 = i)` will generate a compile-time error.

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense on its own merits, Yoda conditions notwithstanding.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using the simpler `list<Tick>::iterator iter;`?

Comment: Sorry, this was from an example left over where I was using cpp linq and it required that. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edits to the question, I think I can write a better answer than what I had before.

First, write a comparison function for `Tick`s that uses their timestamps:

```
bool CompareTicks(const Tick& l, const Tick& r)
{
   return l.timestamp < r.timestamp;
}
```

Now use the function with `std::upper_bound`:

```
// Get an iterator pointing to the first element in ticks that is > 214
// I'm assuming the second parameter to Tick's ctor is the timestamp
auto itAbove = std::upper_bound(ticks.begin(), ticks.end(), Tick(Vec3(0, 0, 0), 214), CompareTicks);
if(itAbove == ticks.end())
   ; // there is nothing in ticks > 214. I don't know what you want to do in this case.
```

This will give you the first element in ticks that is > 214. Next, you can use `lower_bound` to find the first element that is >= 214:

```
// get an iterator pointing to the first element in ticks that is >= 214
// I'm assuming the second parameter to Tick's ctor is the timestamp
auto itBelow = std::lower_bound(ticks.begin(), ticks.end(), Tick(Vec3(0, 0, 0), 214), CompareTicks);
```

You have to do one extra step with `itBelow` now to get the first element before 214, taking care not to go past the beginning of the list:

```
if(itBelow == ticks.begin())
   ; // there is nothing in ticks < 214. I don't know what you want to do in this case.
else
   --itBelow;
```

Now, assuming you didn't hit any of the error cases, `itAbove` is pointing to the first element > 214, and `itBelow` is pointing to the last element < 214.

This assumes your `Tick`s are in order by timestamp, which seems to be the case. Note also that this technique will work even if there are multiple 214s in the list. Finally, you said the list is short so it's not really worth worrying about time complexity, but this technique could get you logarithmic performance if you also replaced the `list` with a `vector`, as opposed to linear for iterative approaches.

Comment: <= isn't valid for checking an iterator I guess. It gives me a compile error on that. Checking iter == before --iter didn't work. It still fell through.

Comment: You're right; I missed that ticks was a `list` and not a `vector`; <= won't work for `list` (I'll edit). As for the third sentence, I'd have to see what you tried to evaluate why it didn't work.

Comment: Further; I don't quite understand what you're trying to do in the loop. `--iter` can never == `ticks.end()` since the for loop terminates as soon as `iter == ticks.end()`. And do you really intend to decrement iter twice within the loop body?

Comment: I didn't have the check at all at first and as long as the entries meet the criteria everything works fine. If the entries are as in my post then it blows up. So I was just trying something. If I don't try something with an error everyone on stackoverflow freaks out on me.

Comment: I'm basically trying to find the 2 ticks that are between the number (200 in this case but that's just an example. it's variable in the real program)

Comment: I think I get it now after your edits. Revised answer.

Comment: Getting compile error: error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const' inside algorithm

Comment: Apparently your `Tick`s aren't comparable. See my edit again. :)

Comment: I had to switch < to > in the compare but then it worked. Now this is doing 2 iterations over the list right? This does work and I'll give credit because it's great, but I have to assume 1 iteration over the list could do the job more efficiently?

Comment: It's doing 2 O(log(N)) processes instead of 1 O(N) process. So it's even better than iterating. :)

Comment: This is great then! Thank you. In case you are wondering why I need to do this, I'm working on a multi-player game and the Entity Interpolation part of this site: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking explains introducing render lag and doing interpolation to get smooth movement from remote clients on local client. So the 214 is the render time and the server is sending 10 ticks a second to each client of all remote clients. This helps me find the 2 ticks that I need to interpolate between. I did this with cpp linq but it was 2 queries and not very efficient.

Comment: Ah. Given that this is performance critical code, you might actually do (fractionally) better using lower_bound to find itBelow, then scanning upwards from it until you get something > the target value (should require no more than 2 increments assuming there aren't multiple elements in the list with the same timestamp).

Comment: "assuming there is only 1 214 in the list" - There is no 214 in the list so not sure what you mean with this. The value I send (214 in this case) will never be in the list. It's about finding the above/below the value I send it. This "214" value is actually the current time - 100 ms (lag) on every game update. So it's constantly changing and is never meant to actually be in the list, but timestamps on either side of it should be and if they aren't then I don't update that remote clients position. I'll check out reversing this though for speed. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it's probably not a big deal. The list will only ever have 5 elements so I'm sure this is fast enough. I'm constantly pushing to the front new ticks and popping from the back the last old tick to maintain 5 total elements at all times. So going through 5 elements should be really fast right.

Comment: @user441521, Is `ticks` always sorted? Even though you are constantly pushing to the front and popping from the back?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your core question is simple. Don't increment if you are at the end. Don't decrement if you are at the start.

Before incrementing, check.

```
if ( iter == ticks.end() )
```

Before decrementig, check.

```
if ( iter == ticks.begin() )
```

**Your particular example**

Looking at what you are trying to accomplish, I suspect you meant to use:

```
        if (iter != ticks.begin())
```

instead of

```
        if (--iter != ticks.end())
```

**Update**

It seems you are relying on the contents of your list being sorted by timestamp.

After your comment, I think what you need is:

```
    if (214>= t.timestamp)
    {
        prior = t;
        if (++iter != ticks.end())
        {
            next = *iter;
            if ( 214 <= next.timestep )
            {
               found = true;
               break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 2**

I agree with the comment made by @crashmstr. Your logic can be:

```
    if (214 <= t.timestamp)
    {
        next = t;
        if ( iter != ticks.begin())
        {
            prior = *--(iter);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I use that the entries I get back are 100 & 200. That's not right. I want the entry directly "below" my value (200 in this case) and the entry directly "above" my value (200). In my example (I changed it to 214 now to make it less confusing) there is no example above 214, so I don't want anything then. I need below and above entries to my value (214 in this case)

Comment: @user441521 you say "above" and "below", do you really mean "before" and "after" with respect to the iteration? Or do you mean something else? Because this answer seems like it is correct from my understanding.

Comment: Entries are always be added to this list and the last value is a timestamp in ms and it's always in order. So as I loop through the list I'm checking to find the 2 entries where the number I pass in is between. So if I had another entry of 300 in my example the "right" answer I want back is the 200 AND 300 entry. If there is no 300 entry then for my value of 214 I don't want anything. I've already went over the max timestamp of 200 or I don't need anything.

Comment: @R Sahu That is returning the 200 and 100 entry. It's making it inside the if check which my expected result is that it wouldn't.

Comment: @user441521 then I think your logic needs a reboot. Right now you check for `214 >= t.timestamp`, but it sounds like you want `t.timestamp >= 214` instead.

Comment: This errors in the for loop after a couple times. I think because of the ++iter if check is increasing it when really we want to increase for the check but not for the loop.

Comment: Regarding your second update. That works with the given entries to the list in my post. However if I make an entry where the timestamp is 300, then this doesn't work. The reason being 214  is <= 300 so it goes into that if check, but iter != ticks.begin() fails because 300 is the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with `std::adjacent_find` from the standard library `<algorithm>`. By default `std::adjacent_find` looks for two consecutive *identical* elements but you can provide your own function to define the relationship you are interested in.

Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct matcher
{
    matcher(int value) : target(value) {}
    bool operator()(int lo, int hi) const {
        return (lo < target) && (target < hi);
    }
    int target;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<int> ticks = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };

    auto it = std::adjacent_find(ticks.begin(), ticks.end(), matcher(214));

    if (it != ticks.end()) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ' << *std::next(it) << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs `200 300`, the two "surrounding" values it found.